# Acces violation during debugging an OpenCV project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to run an Visual Studio 2013 program with OpenCV library but it doesn't work because I have an Access violation executing location. I've read other posts but it still doesn't work.

Here is full code of program:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
     Mat image = imread(argv[1], -1);
     if (img.empty())
         return -1;
     namedWindow("Example", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
     imshow("Example", img);
     waitKey(0);
     destroyWindow("Example");
}
```

Error message:

[image]

Comment: It should be `Mat img = ...` instead of `Mat image = ... ` Is just a typo?

Comment: it does't matter is like a variabile name

Comment: In one case it will compile, in the other it won't. I think it matters after all... :D

Comment: However, aside from that the code is perfectly fine. You probably have some configuration issue. Without further configuration settings or specific error messages, it's very hard to tell.

Comment: yes i've made an childhood mistake but i're recorrected and same error

Comment: Please post the library directory, and the addition dependencies

Comment: i don't get it what you say. I ve linked all libraries of OpenCV well because i've tested another program and it worked